# Error installing eth-brownie. (with pipx)

Tags: python, pip, solidity, hardhat, pipx

Tried installing with `pipx install brownie`
After the error below, I also tried `pipx install cytoolz` to no avail. fml.

```
pip failed to build package:
    cytoolz

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23087:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23092:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23176:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/1300 , https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz/issues/151 . Don't be so fast to upgrade to Python 3.10, the ecosystem is not ready yet.

Answer (score 4):

Was able to download Brownie-Eth  on Python 3.10.2 using the following methods:

1. Made sure cytoolz was uninstalled
   `python3 -m pip uninstall cytoolz`
2. Installed Cython, Cytoolz, and Brownie-Eth Using Pip
   `python3 -m pip install --user cython`
   `python3 -m pip install --user cytoolz`
   `python3 -m pip install --user eth-brownie`
3. Confirmed Brownie-Eth Installation
   `brownie --version`

Source: https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/1315

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using `pip3 install eth-brownie`

I was also having trouble with `pipx upgrade eth-brownie` for which I used `pip3 install --upgrade eth-brownie` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually remove libpng and re-install it with `pip install dlib --no-cache`

if you don't have libpng installed just `pip install dlib --no-cache`

Worked well for me. solution here https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/1694